# Importing img in QGIS - Unsupported Data Source: "file.img" is not a supported raster data source

Tags: qgis, raster, import, land-cover

I know there are similar questions out there, but none of them answer my question/are helpful for a ***complete*** beginner. I can code on R, but am completely unfamiliar with coding in QGIS.

I am trying to calculate landcover classes at varying distances from a center point, using a colleague's protocol. (Everything works for him, same version as me- QGIS 3.20.3 Odense.) I have downloaded the data from [NLCD 2019 Land Cover Database](https://www.mrlc.gov/data/nlcd-2019-land-cover-conus), and it gives an XML, IMG,RDE, RRD files. I am trying to import the IMG file because a colleague uses this technique with the "Open Source Manager--> Raster" tool. However, this is where the error comes up.

I am not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Is this from the 2Gb zip file at the Download link?

Comment: Works perfectly for me. You should also have a very large .ige file (26Gb) but you don't mention it. Although it works mostly okay without it, its only needed at large zoom levels, and if you open the .img file it will read from the .ige as needed. Also check settings: go to Settings.. Options... GDAL section and check the HFA (Erdas Imagine Images) driver is enabled.

Comment: Yes, this is from the 2Gb zip file. I have the .ige file in the folder as well, and made sure that the HFA is enabled, yet I still have the error come up. I will try again on a different computer just in case that makes a difference. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: How are you trying to "import" it precisely? I use Layer.. Add Layer.. Add Raster Layer.. menus.